# XML parsing hangs on large (but not that large) file

Tags: python, xml, memory

I am using python's excellent `xml` module to handle some xml files I have.  One of these files is 250+ MB.  While parsing, it appears to hang.  Running `top` shows that it is slowly filling my memory, then starts swapping, but does not return for over an hour (at which point I kill the process and search SO).

I am staring the process like so:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('some_xml_file.xml')
```

But that's as far as any of my attempts go.  Smaller files are working just fine, but this one large file is breaking things.

What is filling all (4 GB) of my memory, and how can I avoid this?

Comment: You should iteratively parse the file, if possible. http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`xml.etree.ElementTree` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) has this paragraph documented:

> If you don’t mind your application blocking on reading XML data but
>   would still like to have incremental parsing capabilities, take a look
>   at `iterparse()`. *It can be useful when you’re reading a large XML
>   document and don’t want to hold it wholly in memory.*

Consider using [`iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) to process your XML file *incrementally*.

Plus, you should consider switching to [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/index.html) as it is generally faster and more memory-friendly in general, source:

- http://lxml.de/performance.html